# Magento flat rate shipping for Specific State or Postcode

Tags: php, shipping-methods

In backend configuration we can only select country for `Ship to Specific Countries` , I want to do that for state. So that flat rate will be enable for newyork state only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is how I managed to do this. We need to override core model class

`Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Flatrate` and add filter for state in the function.

```
public function checkAvailableShipCountries(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
{
    if($request->getDestRegionCode() != 'NY'){
        return false;
    }else{
        return  parent::checkAvailableShipCountries($request);
    }
}
```

We can get shipping form information in `$request` object.

Comment: While a module would be better practice, this is excellent and I see how this can be modified to making a large amount of conditionals -  nice code.